# TYPO3 - Howto restrict all pages by frontend user login but the login page itself

Tags: typo3

I would like to restrict all pages of a website by the frontend user login. Therefor I would like to add "Show at any login" in the page settings of the root page and tick the checkbox "Extend to Subpages". So all pages are only accessible, if the user is logged in.

But:
How can I show the login form now? Are there beste practices?

First idea for the page tree:

```
- root page (with login form)
  - Home page <-- Password protection starts here and cascades down to all subpages
    - Subpage
    - more pages...
```

But how can I redirect to the homepage, if the user is already logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might put the pages side by side:

```
- root (login) (visible only, without login)
- homepage (visible only with login)
  - subpage1
  - subpage2  
  :
```

but you probably need another page on top

```
- top (Shortcut: redirects to first subpage)
  - root (login) (visible only without login)
  - homepage (visible only with login)
    - subpage1
    - subpage2  
    :
```

Comment: Even though I don't get any output with the solution in my answer (it works for me), it felt more safe, to restrict the pages in TYPO3 to be seen by frontend users only. So I restructured my page tree like your second example and it works out perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did not restrict the pages itself, but added the following typoscript:

```
// redirect to login page
[loginUser = ] && [globalVar = TSFE:id != {$loginPage}]
    config.additionalHeaders.10 {
        header = Location: /index.php?id={$loginPage}
    }
[global]
```

This typoscript checks, whether a frontend user is logged in and is not on the login page. If the user is **not** logged in **and** **not** on the login page, it will redirect to the login page.

Comment: that would mean: your page is generated and delivered, it just contains a redirect. in this way information, which should be protected by login can be obtained without login: just get the first server response (HTML) before the redirect is working.

Comment: at least I would combine this with a changed page rendering: in case of no login render a static text instead of the content column

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ As I am very concerned about security: Are you sure, that the page content of a page will be outputed before the redirect? How can I reproduce this behaviour? When I call a restricted page, I get a redirect with the status code 302, but no content.

Comment: If you have not configured a 404 you automatically should be rewritten to the next visible page up in your rootline. At least that was in earlier versions. In this way no content of a restricted page should be visible as the page has no output itself. Your typescript could only be visible if you refer that pages, and as the content itself is not restricted I would assume it gets rendered. Try a network inspector of your browser and look into the responses